# Ignore method during Proguard Obfuscation

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

I have been trying desperately to ignore the following method during Proguard obfuscation:

```
package com.foo.me;

public class MyClass extends Activity implements Callback  {

   ...

   public void setButtonColor(String color, Button button){ 
      ...
   }

   ...

}
```

I feel like I've been through all the answers here with no luck.  Can any share the correct statement to skip over this method with Proguard?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can keep ProGuard from removing or renaming the class and the method with this configuration:

```
-keep class com.foo.me.MyClass {
    public void setButtonColor(java.lang.String, android.widget.Button);
}
```

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Processing callback methods](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#callback)